# Monitor mode on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)

Tags: linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wifi

I tried to enter monitor mode with my wlan-usb stick on my raspberry pi following this two instructions:

- https://github.com/hexameron/rtlwifi
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365487/kali-linux-on-raspberry-pi-wlan0-monitor-mode

I'm using the following wlan-stick:

Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

however, if I try to load the new driver with

> modprobe rtl8192cu

i get the following error:

> ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8192cu': Exec format error

any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: yes, i'm talking about the WIFI Monitor Mode! Have removed the arm-tag

Comment: The error is not related to monitor mode. It looks like you are not even able to load the driver module at all. What kernel are you using? Is it the same the drivers were compiled for?

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8192cu': Exec format error means that this module is not for your current kernel, you can recompile kernel with rtl8192cu module enabled and then install it. Don`t know if driver if this chipset in rpi kernel supports monitor mode.

This is kernel source - https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
And instruction on building - http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation